# Run itext script as cups filter

Tags: debian, pdf, cups, lpr

I have an itext script to apply some customisations to pdf files. These need to be done on-the-fly.

I can easily do it this way :

```
java -cp ".:itext5.jar" pdflayout input.pdf | lpr -P CP800/print
```

But would rather set up some shareable cups queue that would run the script, so that our graphics people can print to it directly.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

O/S is Debian Sqeeze.